# Git tag of latest commit in a branch in Azure DevOps YAML

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml, git-tag

I have a YAML as follows:

```
name: 

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: 
    type: git
    name: 
    ref: refs/tags/2.0.2304.54

trigger:
- develop
- main


pool:
  vmImage: 

variables:
  

parameters:
  

stages:
```

I need to check if tag mentioned in '**ref: refs/tags/2.0.2304.54**' matches the tag in the latest commit of '***main***' branch. For example, in the below image, latest commit in main branch has 4 tags and one tag matches what's mentioned in ref in YAML.

[image]

Is it possible to check that using Azure DevOps API?